# onPress called on load

Tags: react-native

I have added a function to the `onPress` method but the function is automatically triggered on loading the app. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.showMenu()}>
   <View></View>
</TouchableHighlight>

showMenu(){
   this.state.showMenu = true;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You should only bind the method on onPress. But you are calling it. Change the onPress as

onPress={this.showMenu.bind(this)}

Comment: This didn't work for me, but this did: onPress={() => this.showMenu()}

Answer (score 3):

You are actually executing the function from within the onPress directive.

You should use

```
onPress={this.showMenu}
```

Without the parenthesis, the function will not trigger at loading, only when the user triggers it.

Comment: I still can't believe how often this trips me up. :)

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who have the same problem, but need to pass data add the data you want to pass as second argument in the bind function:

```
onPress={this.showMenu.bind(this, data)}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using functional components you can go with
`onPress={() => showMenu()}`